# Why am I not getting the desired result to simplify and derive $y^2 - z^2$?

Tags: quadratics

I completed my high-school maths test and got $96$% which I was very proud of (not meaning to boast). But there was one question which I got $2$ marks on instead of $4$ and didn't know why when I looked back at my results.

> $\tag{4 marks}$ **Question 8:**
>
> Derive $y^2 - z^2$ from $(y + z)^2$ and then convert it into the quadratic form: $$ax^2 + bx + c = 0 : (a, b, c, x) \in \mathbb{R}, \ a\neq 0, \ x = y + z$$ How must you then show that: $$(y + z)^2 = \frac{-b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$
>   and derive $y^2 - z^2$ from the $RHS$? What is the value of $\Delta$?

**My Attempt:**

I know that $\Delta = \text{discriminant}, b^2 - 4ac$. I also know that $RHS = \text{Right Hand Side}$. I also know that the numerator of the quadratic formula does not include $\pm$ because $\forall n\in \mathbb{R}, \ n^2 > 0$ meaning that there cannot exist $-\sqrt{\Delta}$. But I also know how to expand $(y + z)^2$
$$\begin{align} (y + z)^2 &= y^2 + z^2 + 2yz \\
\implies y^2 - z^2 &= (y + z)^2 - 2yz - 2z^2 \\
&= (y + z)^2 - (2yz + 2z^2) \\
&= (y + z)^2 - 2(yz + z^2) \\
&= (y + z)^2 - 2z(y + z) \\
\implies \frac{y^2 - z^2}{2z} &= \frac{(y + z)^2 - 2z(y + z)}{2z} \\
&= \frac{(y + z)^2}{2z} - \frac{\require{cancel}\cancel{2z}(y + z)}{\cancel{2z}} \\
&= \frac{(y + z)^2}{2z} - (y + z) \\
\implies 0 &= \frac{(y + z)^2}{2z} - (y + z) - \frac{y^2 - z^2}{2z} \\
&= \frac{1}{2z}(y + z)^2 + (-1)(y + z) + \bigg(-\frac{y^2 - z^2}{2z}\bigg) \rightarrow 0 = ax^2 + bx + c  \\
\therefore y + z &= \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - 4\times \frac{1}{2z}\times \big(-\frac{y^2 - z^2}{2z}\big)}}{2\times \frac{1}{2z}} \\
&= \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + \cancel{2z}\big(\frac{y^2 - z^2}{\cancel{2z}}\big)}}{\frac{\cancel{2}}{\cancel{2}z}} \\
&= \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + y^2 - z^2}}{z} \\
\end{align}$$
However, it is here that I stumble into a problem:
$$\because y + z = z + y \implies \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + y^2 - z^2}}{z} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + z^2 - y^2}}{y} \implies y = z$$
and thus it is incorrect and I cannot continue from here.

---

**Correction:**

I asked my maths teacher where I went wrong, and he said that in the equation:
$$y^2 - z^2 = (y + z)^2 - 2z(y + z)$$
I made the mistake of dividing both sides by $2z$, when from this I should have subtracted $y^2 - z^2$ to get $0$ already so that:
$$\begin{align} 0 &= (y + z)^2 - 2z(y + z) - (y^2 - z^2) \\ 
\therefore y + z &= \frac{2z + \sqrt{(-2z)^2 + 4(y^2 - z^2)}}{2} \\
&= \frac{2z + \sqrt{4z^2 + 4(y^2 - z^2)}}{2} \\
&= \frac{2z + \sqrt{4(z^2 + y^2 - z^2)}}{2} \\
&= \frac{2z + \sqrt{4y^2}}{2} \\
&= \frac{2z + \sqrt{4}\sqrt{y^2}}{2} \\
&= \frac{2z + 2y}{2} \\
&= \frac{\cancel{2}(z + y)}{\cancel{2}} \\
&= y + z \\
\end{align}$$
and thus I can continue from here, deriving $y^2 - z^2$ from the quadratic formula. But what I do not understand is:
$$\frac{y^2 - z^2}{2z} = \frac{(y + z)^2 - 2z(y + z)}{2z} \iff y^2 - z^2 = (y + z)^2 - 2z(y + z)$$
$$\therefore 0 = \frac{(y + z)^2}{2z} - (y + z) - \frac{y^2 - z^2}{2z} \iff 0 = (y + z)^2 - 2z(y + z) - (y^2 - z^2)$$
So why am I not getting the desired result? Could you please explain why? I would mostly appreciate it if you did not use different mathematical techniques in answering my question as opposed to *quadratic techniques* since this test was chiefly concerned on understanding quadratic equations (including *completing the square* and graphing). Other mathematical techniques could also be foreign to my understanding of mathematics so far; compared to most users here, I am not highly skilled in mathematics. If you are willing to not (just) include quadratic equations as a way of answering my question, please be very clear and show me step by step.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: where have you used $x=y+z$ as stated in the question?

Comment: I turned it into the quadratic form. I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: FYI, regarding your recent suggested edits: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17132/228959

Comment: @Glorfindel hah ok. I was just bored and began editing. I will perhaps post a question on the math meta about my recent edits. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, when you divide by $2z$, you automatically exclude the case when $z=0$ and this case must be done separately.

But to the main question. The problem is that
$$
\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\times\frac{1}{2z}\times\left(-\frac{y^2-z^2}{2z}\right)}}{2\times \frac{1}{2z}}
\not=
\frac{1+\sqrt{1+2z\left(\frac{y^2-z^2}{2z}\right)}}{\frac{2}{2z}},
$$
but
$$
\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\times\frac{1}{2z}\times\left(-\frac{y^2-z^2}{2z}\right)}}{2\times \frac{1}{2z}}
=
\frac{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2-z^2}{z^2}}}{\frac{2}{2z}},
$$
that is of course equal to $z+y$ for $y\geq 0$. But again, in this scenario, you exclude the case $z=0$.

Comment: I see what you mean. That part I found a little bit tricky but I just cancelled out the negatives and simplified $\frac{4}{2z} = 2z$. What I should have done was multiply the two fractions together and *then* simplify by cancelling out the $4$'s and etc. Thank you so much though! :)

Comment: $$(+1) \ \ \checkmark$$